# How to parse comma delimited list and join those values on another table and reconcatenate?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to parse a semicolon delimited list of values, join on another table using the values and return values from that other table and re-concatenate into a new field.

Here are the examples:

Table A:

[image: Table A]

Here is the table with the PFD values:

Table B:

[image: Table B]

Here is the results I'd like:

Table C:

[image: Table C]

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: If you're on sql server 2017+ Check out [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: This is a flaw in the schema design. Never a good idea to put delimited data into a column. It's a sign of a missing table.

Comment: I'm not on 2017 unfortunately :( But I have tried this and my thoughts are to put this in a sub query so I can join on the value column, and then concatenate both fields using another query.

`SELECT
 [NAME]
 ,[ALIAS]
 ,[DEVICE_PLATFORM_ID],[value]
FROM [RND_DB].[RnD_STG].[DM_PROJECT_S]
 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT([DEVICE_PLATFORM_ID], ';')
WHERE [DEVICE_PLATFORM_ID] IS NOT NULL AND [DEVICE_PLATFORM_ID] NOT IN ('Not Applicable')`

Comment: Ideally, you should be looking to fixing your design. Don't store delimited data in your database. Normalise your design, and then the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way it has to be.  Users submit records via PowerApps and they are able to "multi-select' which we concatenate as I've shown.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: *I'm not on 2017* - what is your version - `select @@version`

Comment: "which we concatentate".... well _don't do that_. They should be going into separate records in a different table, linked back to the record in the main table via foreign key.

Comment: A bit odd to have voted to close as needing detail or clarity - it's perfectly understandable and answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using at least SQL Server 2016, you can use a combination of `string_split` and `for xml path` as follows:

```
select *
from tableA
cross apply (
    select stuff((
        select concat(';', b.alias)
        from String_Split(device_platform_id,';')
        join tableB b on b.name=value
        for xml path ('')
    ),1,1, '') Device_Platform_Alias
)d
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=584c09a6d9ed9d0efe3d1e166af8a5d5)

If you happen to be using a version prior to 2016 you can use this alternative method that uses xml to split the value on ';' instead of the `string_split` function:

```
select *
from tableA
cross apply (
    select stuff((
        select concat(';', b.alias)
        from (
          select value = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
          from ( 
            select x = convert(xml, '<i>' + replace(device_platform_id, ';', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
          ) as a cross apply x.nodes('i') as y(i)
        )v
      join tableB b on b.name=value
      for xml path ('')
    ),1,1, '') Device_Platform_Alias
)d
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=ae2d7bb08381ad88d964f3db4633c979)